# Value of the Infinite Sum of Vector Projections

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Suppose that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are vectors such that

$|u_1| = 2$, $|u_2| = 3$, and $u_1 · u_2 = 5$.

Define the vectors $u_3, u_4, u_5, u_6, . . .$ by

$u_3 = proj_{u_1} u_2$,

$u_4 = proj_{u_2} u_3$,

$u_5 = proj_{u_3} u_4$, ...

(and so on). Find the value of the infinite sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |u_n|$$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the formula for projections:
$$\text{proj}_a b = \left(\frac{a\cdot b}{a\cdot a} \right)a.$$
Using this,
$$u_3=\text{proj}_{u_1}u_2 = \left(\frac{u_1 \cdot u_2}{u_1\cdot u_1}\right)u_1$$
and so the norm of this vector is
$$\|u_3\| = \left|\frac{u_1\cdot u_2 }{u_1\cdot u_1}\right|\|u_1\|.$$
You should plug in all the correct values in these equations (keeping in mind that for any vector $a$, $a\cdot a = \|a\|^2$). Now continue again to compute $u_4 = \text{proj}_{u_2}u_3$ and $\|u_4\|$, and so on. You should start to see a pattern.

---

To find $u_2 \cdot u_3$ note that $u_3$ is a scalar multiple of $u_1$. So:
$$u_2 \cdot u_3 = u_2 \cdot \left(\frac{u_1\cdot u_2}{u_1\cdot u_1}\right)u_1= \left(\frac{u_1\cdot u_2}{u_1\cdot u_1}\right) u_2\cdot u_2$$
and you know all all of the quantities involved here.

Notice that $u_4$ will be a scalar multiple of $u_2$ since it is a projection onto $u_2$. Then $u_5$ will be a scalar multiple of $u_3$ which is a scalar multiple of $u_1$, etc. So you will always be able to compute the dot products you need.

Comment: Right, but how do I find either the vector $u_1$ with the information given or $u_2\cdot u_3$ with only their magnitudes?

Comment: @moosene See my edit. You cannot "solve" for $u_1$, but you can still compute $u_2\cdot u_3$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just confused by your notation in the edit, the $= \cdot u_3$ in the middle is throwing me off. Not sure if this is a typo or what it means.

Comment: @moosene Typo. ${}$

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding how to get from $u_2 \cdot u_3 = u_2 \cdot \left(\frac{u_1\cdot u_2}{u_1\cdot u_1}\right)u_1$ to $\left(\frac{u_1\cdot u_2}{u_1\cdot u_1}\right) u_2\cdot u_2$

Comment: @moosene That is the property that for any vectors $u,v$ and any real number $a$ it holds that
$$u \cdot (av) = (au) \cdot v = a(u \cdot v).$$
So I pulled the coefficient out to the left and was a little loose with my use of parentheses, since the above property shows it doesn't matter.